# Const keyword appended to the end of a function definition... what does it do?

Tags: c++, constants

Suppose I define a function in C++ as follows:

```
void foo(int &x) const {
  x = x+10;
}
```

And suppose I call it as follows:

```
int x = 5;
foo(x);
```

Now typically (without the `const` keyword), this would successfully change the value of `x` from the caller's perspective since the variable is passed by reference. Does the `const` keyword change this? (i.e. From the caller's perspective, is the value of `x` now 15?)

I guess I'm confused as to what the `const` keyword does when it is appended to the end of a function definition... any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your example is incomplete, since the `const` qualifier can only be applied to class member functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This won't work.  You can only const-qualify a *member function*, not an ordinary nonmember function.

For a member function, it means that the implicit `this` parameter is const-qualified, so you can't call any non-const-qualified member functions or modify any non-mutable data members of the class instance on which the member function was called.

Comment: So does it essentially make `this` a constant within the method? Or is there more to it?

Comment: @dfetter88:  That's exactly what it does.  In a member function that is not const qualified, `this` is of type `T*`.  In a member function that is const qualified, `this` is of type `const T*`.

Comment: @defetter: There's nothing more to your particular example, since it's ill-formed. Had it been a member function of the form `R function(Args) cv`, the type of `this` is `cv class_type*`. Do you have a [C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: And if you want to do what you described, prevent `x` from being changed, you would define the function as `void foo(const int &x)`

Comment: The C++ FAQ handles this: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.10.